# Exporting to GraphML instead of GML (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, export, gml

Would there be a way to export a layer (say, a multistring) to a GraphML file instead of GML. Every time I try to export a layer I only see the option for GML and have still yet to find a way to convert GML to GraphML either

Comment: The list of GDAL vector drivers is in https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/index.html. GraphML is not supported. There is some support for graphs in GDAL but it is a bit special and as far as I know those features cannot be used through QGIS https://gdal.org/user/gnm_data_model.html.

Comment: Are there alternative ways to convert the GML to GraphML?